# Automate Excel worksheet to apply information in specific row to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheets setup in excel. Worksheet 1 is dynamic information that I edit weekly. Worksheet 2 is static and will not change. One column in worksheet 1 numbers that are associated with a particular row in worksheet 2. For example, if worksheet 1 column C has a 4 in it, I'd like to apply what is in row 4 in worksheet 2, to replace that number with text.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense and it sounds like [*Vlookup*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) with a helper column I guess?

Answer (score 0):

If as you stated you already have a pre-filled-in column C that maps a row in Sheet1 to a row in Sheet2, then all you need is the INDEX function to pull information from Sheet2 into Sheet1.

You cannot "replace" the number in Sheet1 col C with information from Sheet2; you need to keep it as the row# into Sheet2.  So you copy the information from Sheet2 into Sheet1 in some other column on Sheet1.  But you can hide Col C in Sheet1 if you do not want to see it for some reason.  Or just move the mapping Column in Sheet1 to some column much further to the right.

If you have multiple columns in Sheet2 to move to Sheet1, just use multiple INDEX functions in the proper Sheet1 columns with the proper Sheet2 column numbers.

A trivial example for pulling one data element from Sheet2 to Sheet1 for row 2 in Sheet1 (replace the *col#inSheet2* with a Sheet2 column number); the dollar-signs are important:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1, Sheet1!$C2, col#inSheet2)
```

If the rows in Sheet1 change, yet there is a per-row key value that maps rows in Sheet1 to Sheet2, then use the MATCH function in Sheet1 col C to get the row# in Sheet2 that maps to Sheet1.  This is particularly true if there are multiple columns of data to transfer from Sheet2 to Sheet1.

And as @L42 mentioned, use VLOOKUP instead if there is just one column to move from Sheet2 to Sheet1, and again the rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2 change weekly, and again there is a per-row key value that maps the two sheets.